# I have installed the Shibboleth 2.6 on Centos 6 (linux) server But I don't know what information I have to add in Apache

Tags: linux, database

I have installed the Shibboleth 2.6 on Centos 6 (linux) server.  But I don't know what additional information I have to add in Apache. I have tried with some information but was facing the issue while starting the Apache. So could anyone please help me in making the shib in running  state.

Comment: **anybody please help me here, it very urgent for me**

Comment: Could you describe in detail operations already performed?